# Using Chrome DevTools Protocol Input.dispatchKeyEvent or Input.dispatchMouseEvent to send an event

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I'm writing a DSL that will interact with a page via Google Chrome's Remote Debugging API.

The INPUT domain (link here:
https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/1-2/Input/) lists two functions that can be used for sending events: **Input.dispatchKeyEvent** and **Input.dispatchMouseEvent**.

I can't seem to figure out how to specify the target `element` as there is no link between the two functions and `DOM.NodeId`, or an intermediate API that accepts a `DOM.NodeId` which then returns an X,Y co-ordinate.

I know that it's possible to use Selenium, but I'm interested in doing directly using WebSockets.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Brief Intro

I'm currently working on a NodeJS interaction library to work with Chrome Headless via the Remote Debugging Protocol. The idea is to integrate it into my colleague's testing framework to eventually replace the usage of PhantomJS, which is no longer being supported.

## Evaluating JavaScript

I'm just experimenting with things currently, but I have a way of evaluating JavaScript on the page, for example, to click on element via a selector reference. It *should* in theory work for anything assuming my implementation isn't flawed.

```
let evaluateOnPage: function (fn) {
    let args = [...arguments].slice(1).map(a => {
        return JSON.stringify(a);
    });

    let evaluationStr = `
        (function() {
            let fn = ${String(fn)};
            return fn.apply(null, [${args}]);
        })()`;

        return Runtime.evaluate({expression: evaluationStr});
    }
}
```

The code above will accept a function and any number of arguments. It will turn the arguments into strings, so they are serializable. It then evaluates an IIFE on the page, which calls the function passed in with the arguments.

### Example Usage

```
let selector = '.mySelector';

let result = evaluateOnPage(selector => {
    return document.querySelector(selector).click();
}, selector);
```

The result of `Runtime.evaluate` is a promise, which when is fulfilled, you can check the result object for a type to determine success or failure. For example, `subtype` may be `node` or `error`.

I hope this may be of some use to you.

Comment: Is there pure Remote Debugging API decision without Javascript (in theory Javascript could be disabled)?

Answer (score 1):

this protocol is probably not the best if you are wanting to click on specific elements rather than clicking on spots on the screen...

It's important to keep in mind that this area of the devtools protocol is intended to emulate the raw input. If you want to try and figure out the position of the elements using the protocol or by running some javascript in the page you could do that, however it might be better to use something like [target.dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) with [MouseEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) and inject the javascript into the page instead.